# Remove duplicates with Pandas in Cloud Datalab (from bigquery) traceback error

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to use the drop_duplicates function in Pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

```
ssc_df = bq.Query(ssc_ciq_match).to_dataframe()
ssc_df.drop_duplicates(ssc_df.ssc_ssc_key, keep = False)
```

I get this error:

```
ErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3b85467271be> in <module>()
----> 1 ssc_df.drop_duplicates(ssc_df.ssc_ssc_key, keep = False)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/util/decorators.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 else:
     90                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         return wrapper
     93     return _deprecate_kwarg

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in drop_duplicates(self, subset, keep, inplace)
   3136         deduplicated : DataFrame
   3137         """
-> 3138         duplicated = self.duplicated(subset, keep=keep)
   3139 
   3140         if inplace:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/util/decorators.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 else:
     90                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         return wrapper
     93     return _deprecate_kwarg
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is that the first parameter (`subset`) should be a string, or list of strings.  Please can you try the following?

```
ssc_df = bq.Query(ssc_ciq_match).to_dataframe()
ssc_df.drop_duplicates('ssc_ssc_key', keep = False)
```

If this does not resolve your issue, please could you provide the full stack trace? The question only contains part of the stack trace.